# Load modal box only if API successfully returns data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a question about uib-modal box. In my angular app, when we click on button EDIT CONFIGURATION, we call modal box, with configuration info. On click, also, we call function for load data in config from API server. Problem is, if the internet speed is slow and server request needs more than 2 sec for response, modal box will be opened without loaded data. If server response is normal, in this case, data will be loaded normally.

My question is, how to wait with load modal box, or show some spinner, until data is loaded.

This is my function where I make a call to API

```
$scope.setDataInConfigList = function () {
            $scope.parcijalniConfigZaPopUp = "";
            $scope.currentKlupaParcijalniConfig = sveKlupeServiceFactoryConfig.get({klupa: $scope.selected.klupe});
            $scope.currentKlupaParcijalniConfig.$promise.then(function (configParcijalni) {

            $scope.parcijalniConfigZaPopUp = configParcijalni;
            $scope.klupaLedconfigVrijemeRada.ledConfigLedSummerTimeMaxTime = $scope.parcijalniConfigZaPopUp.led_band_config.operating_time_schedule.max_operating_hours_summer ? $scope.parcijalniConfigZaPopUp.led_band_config.operating_time_schedule.max_operating_hours_summer : null;
            $scope.klupaLedconfigVrijemeRada.hotspot_user_time_unlimited = $scope.parcijalniConfigZaPopUp.hotspot_user_time_unlimited ? $scope.parcijalniConfigZaPopUp.hotspot_user_time_unlimited : null; 
    });

    };
```

And modal box

```
<button type="button" id="add_new_bench" class="btn btn-default" style="color:#000;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" ng-click=" setDataInConfigList(currentItemtBench.id)">{{'EDIT_CONFIGURATION'| translate}}</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <parcijalni-config></parcijalni-config>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can't quite follow your question? The basic is that you show the modal after an event, then call your ajax/promise and after is fulfilled or rejected hide the modal and show the data or display an error message.

Comment: On the same button, I call modal box and function to make a call to my API. Modal box shows instantly, before server response with data, and because of that, all data in the modal box is empty. My idea is when I click on the button, wait with showing modal box until server response with data, on this way I get normally data in the modal box. I hope you understandme now.

Comment: Ok. if you using the button to show the modal and then call the api. I don't see in your code where you showing the modal.

Comment: How not? In <button></button> tag, you see data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" , and for call function I use ng-click=" setDataInConfigList(currentItemtBench.id)"